# Merge tags [visual-studio-mac] and [visual-studio-for-mac]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are currently two tags [visual-studio-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-mac) and [visual-studio-for-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-for-mac) that refer to the same thing. I suggest to merge these into a single tag, [visual-studio-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-mac) which has tag info and more associated questions.

Comment: You need somebody with enough rep in [visual-studio-mac] to propose a synonym.  I alerted @SushiHangover.

Comment: @HansPassant Done: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-mac/synonyms

Comment: Great, now 4 votes.  I found 3 more users that can vote and alerted them.  @Sushi - please vote too.

Comment: @HansPassant I can not vote : `You can not vote on a tag synonym you created`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've approved the synonym that SushiHangover proposed.